# Update NFT metadata after mint

Tags: anchor, rust, nft, anchor-lang, candy-machine-v2

Just need to know how to update NFT metadata after minting NFT. I am trying to use  `mpl_token_metadata::instruction::update_metadata_accounts_v2` for this. Don't know the correct way to use it or if there is some other way to update metadata.

```
    pub fn update_nft_metadata(ctx: Context<MintNFT>) -> Result<()> {
        let program_id = ctx.accounts.token_metadata_program.key();
        let metadata_account = ctx.accounts.metadata.key();
        let update_authority = ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key();
        let new_update_authority: Option<Pubkey> = Some(ctx.accounts.mint_authority.key());
        let data: DataV2 = DataV2 {
            name: ("superNFT").to_string(),
            symbol: ("SMB").to_string(),
            uri: ("abc.com").to_string(),
            seller_fee_basis_points: 1000,
            creators: None,
            collection: None,
            uses: None,
        };

        mpl_token_metadata::instruction::update_metadata_accounts_v2(
            program_id,
            metadata_account,
            update_authority,
            new_update_authority,
            Some(data),
            Some(false),
            Some(true),
        );
        
        Ok(())
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This does seams the right way you have to invoke the CPI as well like this :-

```
 program::invoke_signed(
    &update_ix,
    &[
        ctx.accounts.metadata.to_account_info(),
        ctx.accounts.update_auth.to_account_info(),
    ],
   pda_signer,
)?;
```

Let me you if you get any error message

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to do it on your finger.
candy machine v2 supports create & update nft.
and it's very easy to use.

please reference this.

https://github.com/metaplex/metaplex

in this case, we've used candy machine to mint and update nft.
please contact me if you've got a problem.